# Error con efecto parpadeo en CSS

Tags: css, css3, animación

Estoy trabajando en una página de un juego de terror en la cual la capa de fondo es una imagen de terror, pero la capa de frente es de color negro.

Lo que quiero lograr es un efecto en el cual se vea una imagen negra con letras y que en determinado momento el fondo negro haga un parpadeo (estilo flashes) y se vea la imagen de fondo. El estilo es como en los vídeos en el cuales está el cuarto oscuro y la luz hace flashes y se ve un fondo terrorífico.

> El efecto funciona bien, pero el problema es que la primer capa no la toma pero si hacen el efecto las letras, lo cual no es necesario hacerlo y no puedo resolverlo.

```css
body {
background-image: url(https://memeworld.funnyjunk.com/pictures/A+chernobyl+horror+story+by+stefan+koidl_27d56d_7079691.jpg);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}


.flicker-4 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
 -webkit-animation: flicker-4 8s linear infinite both;
         animation: flicker-4 8s linear infinite both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flicker-4 {
    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    31.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    32% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    32.8% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    32.82% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    34.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    35% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.7% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.72% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    36.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    37% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    37.6% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    37.62% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    67.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    68% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    68.4% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    68.42% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    95.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    96% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    96.7% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    96.72% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    98.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    99.6% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    99.62% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
@keyframes flicker-4 {
    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    31.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    32% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    32.8% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    32.82% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    34.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    35% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.7% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.72% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    36.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    37% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    37.6% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    37.62% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    67.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    68% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    68.4% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    68.42% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    95.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    96% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    96.7% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    96.72% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    98.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    99.6% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    99.62% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Terror Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06494d4185.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="flicker-4">
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center pt-5">Terror Site</h1>


</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Codigo actualizado**

```css
body {
background-image: url(https://memeworld.funnyjunk.com/pictures/A+chernobyl+horror+story+by+stefan+koidl_27d56d_7079691.jpg);
background-size: cover;
margin: 0;
}



.flicker-4 {
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
height: 100vh;
-webkit-animation: flicker-4 6s linear infinite both;
animation: flicker-4 6s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes flicker-4 {
    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    31.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    32% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    32.8% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    32.82% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    34.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    35% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.7% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    35.72% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    36.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    37% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    37.6% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    37.62% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    67.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    68% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    68.4% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    68.42% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    95.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    96% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    96.7% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    96.72% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    98.98% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    99.6% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    99.62% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Terror Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06494d4185.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flicker-4">
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center pt-5">Terror Site</h1>

</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Disculpa no termino de entender el problema, ¿podrías ser mas claro?

Comment: Ya actualice la publicacion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lo siguiente en razón de que:**

- El body permanezca independiente con un solo color de fondo
- La *aparición y desaparición*  del `div` sobre el body sea la que de el efecto buscado
- Para el caso del texto, perfectamente lo puedes colocar dentro del `div` incluso dentro de una etiqueta `p` y así aplicarle estilos de manera simple

**Procedimiento**

- El body permanezca independiente con un solo color de fondo
- Al `body` le pondría un color de fondo inicial `black`
- Posterior cargo un `div` con la clase `.fake` al cual le agregaré lo siguiente:

  - La imagen de fondo
  - Le establezco un alto de 100vh para que sea del alto completo del *viewport* y así logremos cubrir el `body` visible
  - Al `body` le quito los márgenes que pudiera tener para que el `div` cubra todo el espacio visible
  - Yo agregaría el valor en la animación de `alternate` para poder invertir la secuencia de pasos que sigue la misma cuando acaba

Quedando así la propuesta

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body{
          background: black;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .fake {
          background: url(https://memeworld.funnyjunk.com/pictures/A+chernobyl+horror+story+by+stefan+koidl_27d56d_7079691.jpg);
          background-size: cover;
          height: 100vh;
          animation: image-generated 2s alternate infinite;
        }
        
        @keyframes image-generated
        {
          0% {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          10% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          15% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          20% {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          23% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          30% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          40% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          50% {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          60% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          70% {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          80% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
          90% {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          100% {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="fake"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Bueno, pude arreglarlo tratando de dejar el `body` independiente de y agregue el `height: 100vh;` en el contenido del color de fondo. Pero igualmente tuve que colocar la imagen dentro del body. Gracias por ayuda!